# rewriting a URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Good morning, I want to create a simple URL which changes a certain URL from let's say index.php to "home", to accomplish this I wrote the code below and saved it as a .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [NC,L]
```

But all this code does is make it possible for a user to access the home page by simply typing the websites name/home but when the user follows a link the URL still shows index.php, how can I go about solving this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `href` of the corresponding `a` tags from `index.php` to `home`.

They are called **symbolic links** and is used for representation. Still the content is available via direct url.

or add the below code in your php page.

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"])===true)
    header('location:home');
```

This will redirect people from the current page to `home` if they directly visited the page

Comment: sorry, but I tried out the first option but all it does is redirect to the localhost/home

Comment: remove the slash `/`. Try `home` instead of `/home`

Comment: I wouldn't call this a "symbolic link"; it is simply a URL. A _symbolic link_ is a filesystem construct.

Comment: @MrWhite Afaik, the word used to represent it is symlink. Since you have experience on `.htaccess`, if you can give me other name, it will be helpful for me in future.

Comment: In some ways, this does behave _like_ a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) (or symlink), however, it is not a _symlink_. A "symlink" is created on the underlying filesystem (`ls -s` on Linux, `mklink` on Windows, `symlink()` in PHP). In fact, if a symlink had been created then there wouldn't be any need for the mod_rewrite directive in the question, since the _filesystem_ would handle it. This is simply "URL-rewriting", as stated in the question title: "rewriting a URL ..."